# How to register a non listed program as default mailto: handler in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mailto

We want to register our mailprogram to open on a **mailto:** click in a browser. We can set Firefox to do so, but not e.g. Edge or IE. When you go to System settings in Windows 10 and look at the "Default apps", the Email option provides Mail, Microsoft Outlook, and "Look for an app in the Store" and not an option to Browse for another program. Changing registry keys in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\Shell\open\command and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\iConnect\Protocol\mailto\shell\open\command
does no long work since W8.

One suggestion I found was that a hashtag in Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto\UserChoice determines the program. I installed fciv.exe via https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841290 to find the hashtag of my program and entered it there without result.

Any suggestions are welcome.

I am currently even thinking about creating a Universal app and have it registered in the store, which is is able to handle mailto and then redirect to any application of choice (an option Windows should have provided in the first place) but I guess that also won't be a straightforward thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

You need to register your application for it to be listed in registered applications can be default first. To do that you need to add in these registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
```

and if your program is a 32-bit on a 64-bit Windows:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\RegisteredApplications]
```

Then you have to declare its capability for mailto protocol. There are a several places in the registry to add. Here is what I use for my program (RDMailto.exe), rename RDMailto to your program name and you will be ok:

```
    Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto]
    @="URL:MailTo Protocol"
    "URL Protocol"=""

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mailto\shell\open\command]
    @="\"RDMailto.exe\" %1"

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RDMailto.Mailto]
    @="URL:MailTo Protocol"
    "URL Protocol"=""

    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\RDMailto.Mailto\shell\open\command]
    @="\"RDMailto.exe\" %1"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto]
    @="URL:MailTo Protocol"
    "URL Protocol"=""

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\mailto\shell\open\command]
    @="\"RDMailto.exe\" %1"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\RDMailto.Mailto]
    @="URL:MailTo Protocol"
    "URL Protocol"=""

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\RDMailto.Mailto\shell\open\command]
    @="\"RDMailto.exe\" %1"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
    "RDMailto"="SOFTWARE\\MQTechnologies\\RDMailto\\Capabilities"

        [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MQTechnologies\RDMailto\Capabilities]
    "ApplicationDescription"="Open mailto on local machine"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MQTechnologies\RDMailto\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
    "mailto"="RDMailto.Mailto"

    [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\RegisteredApplications]
    "RDMailto"="SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\MQTechnologies\\RDMailto\\Capabilities"

      [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MQTechnologies\RDMailto\Capabilities]
    "ApplicationDescription"="Open mailto on local machine"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MQTechnologies\RDMailto\Capabilities\UrlAssociations]
    "mailto"="RDMailto.Mailto"

    [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\mailto]
```

The last line is to dissociate existing program that handles mailto protocol. Be careful if there is any mail client program already installed on the machine like Outlook. Each time Outlook starts it will rewrite (override) the mailto registry key to make it as default mail client program.

I use this with RemoteApp on Windows 2012/R2 and Windows 8.1, it should be the same with Windows 10 (not tested yet).